# how do i properly assign the products variable to the array from the response from my api

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, primevue

im trying to use a primeblocks component and i need to v-bind a the dataTable to the response from my api

this is where im stuck: when i console.log(productData) i get an array containing the array of all my products which came from my api instead of a regular array

```
<template>
    <div>
        <DataTable :value="productData" responsiveLayout="scroll">
            <Column field="SKU" header="Code"></Column>
            <Column field="name" header="Name"></Column>
            <Column field="brand" header="Brand"></Column>
            <Column field="color" header="Color"></Column>
        </DataTable>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

let productData = [];

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            productData: null
        }
    },
    mounted() {
    
        const loadProducts = async () => {
          const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:1337/products")
          productData.value = response.data.products;
        };
        loadProducts()
    }
}
console.log(productData)

</script>
```

this is my console.log

```
[]
value: (87) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
length: 0
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

im clearly doing something wrong, if anyone can point me in the right direction that would be awesome

Comment: You are logging outside of the component (when the component is parsed). You probably want to console inside the `loadProducts` function, after you've awaited `response`. Another problem is `productData` is not reactive. You probably want to do: `this.productData = response.data.products`. You don't need the external `productData` (at least in what you've shown so far).

Comment: @tao like this?; `<script>
import axios from 'axios';

let productData = [];

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            productData: null
        }
    },
    mounted() {
    
        const loadProducts = async () => {
          const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:1337/products")
          productData.value = response.data.products;
          console.log(productData)
        };
        loadProducts()
    }
}

</script>` because that give a different response but my actual issue is the th edata isnt getting v-binded in the template

Comment: I haven't used primeblocks so I can't advise on that (check their docs). I've added an answer showing you how I'd write your component (based on what you have). Whether or not `DataTable` expects an array in the `value` property, I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are logging outside of the component (when the component is parsed). You probably want to console inside the `loadProducts` function, after you've awaited `response`.

Another problem is `productData` is not reactive.
You probably want to use: `this.productData = response.data.products`.
You don't need the external productData (at least in what you've shown so far).

Here's how I'd write your component using Options API:

```html
<template>
  <DataTable :value="products" responsiveLayout="scroll">
    <Column v-for="col in columns" :key="col.field" v-bind="col" />
  </DataTable>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  data: () => ({
    products: [],
    columns: [
     { field: 'SKU', header: 'Code' },
     { field: 'name', header: 'Name' },
     { field: 'brand', header: 'Brand' },
     { field: 'color', header: 'Color' }
    ]
  }),
  mounted() {
    axios.get("http://localhost:1337/products")
      .then(({ data }) => this.products = data?.products || [])
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: so the data is displaying in the component but when i try to console.log(products) i get "products is not defined" how come?

Comment: You have to console inside `then`: `.then(({data}) => { console.log(data); this.products = data?products || []}`

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite see why you're using `loadProducts`, since it could also be solved using the `.then` keyword as such (which IMO is a lot neater to look at and also does it asynchronously):

```js
axios.get("http://localhost:1337/products").then(res=>{
   this.productData = res.data.products;
})
```

Also if possible, don't use `null` but `[]` instead when declaring data properties in vue/nuxt.

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

it should be

`productData.push(...response.data.products)`

Comment: hmm now im getting this in my ocnsole; []
0: (87) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

Comment: So did it fix ur problem?

Comment: no its still not showing the data in the dataTable component

Comment: I've edited my code, please try

Comment: i guess that works too but @tao got it all working, thanks tho